# What is the preferred way of passing styles to children in React & Emotion JS?

Tags: reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I'm just getting started with [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) after working with [react-jss](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.5.0) for a few years. One thing I'm struggling to find a good example of is passing (some, possibly dynamic) styles to a child component. In `react-jss` this was pretty trivial:

```
// In SomeParent.jsx
... imports etc ...

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  custom: {
    color: 'blue',
  },
})

export const CustomBody = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return <Body className={classes.custom}>some text</Body>
} 

// In Body.jsx
... imports etc...

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  body: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'black',
  },
})

const Body = ({ children, className }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <p
      className={clsx(
        classes.body,
        className,
      )}
    >
      {children}
    </p>
  )
}
```

Essentially, parent components could create styles and pass any number of related class names via a prop (usually `className` ) to the child, which could then consume them in their own `className` prop, combining them with any other styles the child component needs.

Emotion definitely does allow this same thing, but I can't figure out how they *expect* you to do it.

Semantically on the child-side, it seems like the [styled tagged template literal](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#styling-any-component) takes in `emotion` styles and passes a  `className` prop to the child, which then would work the same way it does in react-jss. However, I find the `styled` syntax to be crazy ugly and hard to parse. I'd rather not fill my parent files up with potentially differently `styled` HOC-wrapped child components.

Functionally, it seems like passing my own prop of `emotion` styles and composing those styles in the child component most closely mirrors `react-jss`, but I can't find any examples in the emotion documentation suggesting that this is something they expect you to do. It's not FORBIDDEN or anything, it's just not highlighted. Does something like the following make sense?

```
// In SomeParent.jsx
... imports etc ...

export const CustomBody = () => {
  return <Body customStyles={css`color: blue`}>some text</Body>
}

// In Body.jsx
... imports etc...

const bodyStyles = css`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
`
const Body = ({ children, customStyles }) => {
  return (
    <p
      css={css`
        ${bodyStyles};
        ${customStyles};
      `}
    >
      {children}
    </p>
  )
}
```

The [composition documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition) makes clear that this will work (and it does), but it doesn't specifically showcase passing styles from one component to another the way the `styled` documentation does. This feels better to me, but I am worried about [the note in the string styles documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#string-styles) which points out that `css` doesn't return a class string, but instead returns a full object that is "understood by emotion at a low level". If this object isn't memoized by `emotion` (I haven't tested this myself yet) then I'm going to end up with a bunch of unnecessary re-renders. I could memoize on the class name string that is included as part of that object, but I'm not sure how consistent that is either.

The last thing that might be relevant is the [class names API](https://emotion.sh/docs/class-names). It looks like this would allow me to create a style and pass it as a `className` string to a child component (much like in `react-jss` and avoiding the re-render problem), but again, having to wrap EVERY child component that accepts a style from a parent in the `ClassNames` component and then dealing with render functions seems crazy.

Am I just missing something here? Has the whole world accepted that `styled` and the styled component pattern is just the way to go with this stuff? Please let me know how you've solved this problem, or point me to the documentation that I've over looked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone finds this post later, I ran my own tests comparing the performance of each of these methods when creating 1000 p tags and coloring them based on their index.

`styled` was the most performant, `ClassNames` was second most performant (with its best performance generally matching the lower end of `styled`'s performance). Passing the `css` tagged template literal directly was much worse than either of the other two, with performance 1.5x to 2x worse than `styled`'s worst performance.

Conditionally styling by passing props is absolutely slower than static styles, and using the [prop filtering](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#customizing-prop-forwarding) for `styled` only decreases performance a small amount over not filtering (probably a good tradeoff to prevent unnecessary re-renders if that's a potential issue).

Comment: I could be wrong and it may be worth testing but I think just passing an object directly to the css prop might be more performant because you don't need the css`` function. For example just passing {color: 'black'} to the css prop works. Also, if you define your css outside of your component that could speed things up to. Like const myStyle =css`color: black` and then passing that. When you pass a tagged template with css`` directly, you're actually calling a function that generates an object for emotion to make sense of during render.In your example I would do css={[bodyStyles, customStyles]}

Comment: This would avoid having to call css`` and having to use string interpolation. Here's a quote from emotions site to example have the css function works. "css from @emotion/react does not return the computed class name string. The function returns an object containing the computed name and flattened styles. " https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop (scroll down to string styles). styled was most likely more performant because you declared it outside of the component itself.